# PHPstorm panels layout

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm panels layout by default is similar to:

```
 ___________
|  |        |
|__|________|
|___________|
```

Is it possible to change it to following:

```
 ___________
|  |        |
|  |________|
|__|________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, please vote for the [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74140).